# store variable for use later in plsql block

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql

I am very new to plsql and I'm not even sure if I can do what I want.

I'm trying to create a simple plsql block that I can use for multiple databases that will create a pfile in a specific directory that contains a variable that I get via a sql query.

Here's where I am:

```
DECLARE

  dbname v$database.name%TYPE;

BEGIN

  SELECT name INTO dbname FROM v$database;

  IF SQL%FOUND THEN 

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(dbname);

  END IF;

END;

/
```

Here's where I want to get:

```
DECLARE

  dbname v$database.name%TYPE;

BEGIN

  SELECT name INTO dbname FROM v$database;

  IF SQL%FOUND THEN 

        create pfile=/tmp/***dbname***/init***dbname***.ora from spfile;

  END IF;

END;

/
```

How do I take the variable and inject into the create pfile statement?

Comment: Before you shoot yourself in the foot, I'd be asking why you think you want to create a pfile from a pl/sql procedure?  In fact, why you want a pfile at all?  This has all the hallmarks of an [XY question](https://xyproblem.info/)   What _business_ problem are you trying to solve?   A bit to your original question, CREATE PFILE is a directive to sqlplus.  It is not a SQL or PL/SQL statement.

Comment: And what do you mean by "another database"? Oracle's definition which means an entirely different instance of Oracle, or everyone else's definition which means just another schema in the same instance?

Comment: I add the "create pfile" statement to our RMAN jobs just for another level of protection.  I do the same thing with "controlfile to trace".  It just provides one more level of data protection.
What I mean by "another database"... This particular block will run from a scheduler and it would run for each database maintained in the scheduler and I don't want to have a separate job for each database.

Answer (score 0):

I got to where I needed to be.  This seems to work.

```
declare

 dbname varchar2(200);

 sqlstmp varchar2(500);

begin

 select name into dbname from v$database;

 sqlstmp := 'create pfile=''/tmp/'|| dbname ||'/'||dbname||'init.ora'' from spfile';

execute immediate (sqlstmp);

end;

/
```